# Emacs keyboard-shortcut sequences after CapsLock remapping with Authotkey

Tags: windows, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I've made simple remapping of CapsLock to Control with autohotkey:

```
Capslock::Control   ; make Caps Lock the control button
```

This works OK, but in Emacs if I need to do a key sequence like `Ctrl-x Ctrl-f` while *holding the CapsLock key continuously the whole time* what gets registered is `Ctrl-x f`. In order to get the correct sequence I now have to release CapsLock between the keystrokes like `Ctrl-x <release> Ctrl-f` which is very inconvenient.

Is there a way to do the rebinding so that holding CapsLock down will work exactly as holding down the Control button?

I've also tried the following snippet without success:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Emacs
{
CapsLock::
Sendinput {Ctrl Down}
KeyWait, CapsLock
Sendinput {Ctrl Up}
return
}
```

Using `Send` or `Sendplay` in the above instead of `Sendinput` also doesn't solve my problem.

My system:

Windows 7 32bit
AHK v1.1.13.01
Emacs 24.3

Thank you!

Comment: Just use a different program.
KeyTweak and sharpkeys are both freeware and have a simple
GUI to switch Caps Lock to Ctrl.

Comment: OK, I tried KeyTweak and it works, with only problem being the timing on key registration is sometimes off (C-x C-v C-m is always registered as C-x C-m C-v).

Comment: I'd prefer an autohotkey solution but if none is find until the bounty ends I'll give you the points if you submit this as proper answer. Help with the timing issue would be much appreciated too...

Comment: I was using Emacs on Windows 7 for about a year and I haven't had this problem. The issue is that I don't remember now if I was using KeyTweak or sharpkeys. Could you try the other one and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Tried both and both behave the same way, i.e. there is a timing problem and also neither registers doubled keystrokes like `C-c C-c`...

Comment: OK, I'll have a look when I have access to my laptop. I still have Windows there for gaming.
So you're saying that you can't even `C-c C-c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use and it works:

```
*Capslock::LCtrl
```

The asterisk is documented in the help under Keyboard Control > Hotkeys and Hotstrings:

> Wildcard: Fire the hotkey even if extra modifiers are being held down. This is often used in conjunction with remapping keys or buttons. For example:
>
> > *#c::Run Calc.exe  ; Win+C, Shift+Win+C, Ctrl+Win+C, etc. will all trigger this hotkey.
> >
> > *ScrollLock::Run Notepad  ; Pressing Scrolllock will trigger this hotkey even when modifer key(s) are down.
>
> This symbol is ignored on Windows 95/98/ME.

I actually have this one too, <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, if I really want caps lock:

```
<#Capslock::Capslock
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it's not working correctly for you. I added your remapping into my existing script and it seems to work fine. Can you post more of what you have? I have the following commands at the top of mine but I wouldn't think they should affect your problem.

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force
```

The commands [GetKeystate](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm)
and [SetKeyDelay](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tips... the initial flags unfortunately didn't help... problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
CapsLock:: SendInput, {LCtrl Down}
Capslock Up:: SendInput, {LCtrl Up}
```

Comment: Sorry, no luck... same behavior as the other snippets I tried.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with your capslock key.  Have you tried setting another key as Ctrl to see what happens?

Comment: Couple of suggestions, don't know if they will help you.  Try closing every other AHK script that you have running, see if that helps.  If it works in other places, just not in EMACS, try looking into EMACS built-in hotkeys.